# How am I supposed to include LibTIFF (Qt)?

Tags: qt, qimage, libtiff

I tried writing

```
include (C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtimageformats\src\3rdparty\libtiff.pri)
```

in `.pro` file, but received

```
Project has no top-level .qmake.conf file.
```

I tried to

```
#include <C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtimageformats\src\3rdparty\libtiff\libtiff\tiffio.h>
```

, but I believe that's not enough to cover all libtiff functionality.

I just want to include libtiff somehow and write something like

```
TIFF* img = TIFFOpen("1.tif", "r");
uint32 length;
TIFFGetField(img, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &length);
```

and so on. And I cannot use QImage for some reasons.

I'll be thankful for any help attempts.

Answer (score 0):

In general to use a library in Qt you have to specify in your .pro/.pri file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "path\to\the\headers"
LIBS += "path\to\your\lib"
```

and include the header in file where you want to use it.

Comment: Can you clarify: what is meant by "path to your lib"? Path to a specific file with a specific file extension?

Comment: `LIBS += C:\Path\To\Your\library.lib` or as the documentation show:
`LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lmath`